# GroupBy Array based on key and its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, grouping

I have an array of transactions and I want to group the transactions based on the key `timeSent`.

But the `timeSent` is in milliseconds and it is unique. I want the data to be grouped by date.

How do I possibly group an array based on a key but its value?
How should I alter my function?

```js
const transactions = [
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x5677f30d52ccea78e03a80597f978561abf763ec32bc2b2b9b7e3013527c0066",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534488092742,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534488101395,
        "blockNumber": "699851",
        "gasUsed": "28056",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "28056",
        "action": "addSignatory",
        "extraData": "documentId=69b1d781-7b56-4e97-9bc7-c6051df232ca",
        "property": "178"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x043d6f936d89dbe235dfa63c6cc511ddf82c3dc0d7c8a522adee3404ee72120b",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534488050259,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534488057529,
        "blockNumber": "699842",
        "gasUsed": "31512",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "31512",
        "action": "addDocument",
        "extraData": "documentId=69b1d781-7b56-4e97-9bc7-c6051df232ca",
        "property": "178"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xc4a8aef93084733a2155a71ee934dd31466a1de268c77ca3b48e3edf5aaa70ac",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534487694591,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "4300000",
        "timeMined": 1534487695066,
        "blockNumber": "699768",
        "gasUsed": "697650",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "697650",
        "action": "addSpatialUnit",
        "extraData": "propertyId=1"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x65a289854f5afc2a765e7217f1b5e1614a4318baa7ad9c298e2aa9f83cb4bce6",
        "fromAddress": "0x08a863e866cd8fe15d3c1e45c5d66e85440d724f",
        "timeSent": 1534485760789,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485766989,
        "blockNumber": "699384",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xfffd1812abccfd7e43ad326411060a3138ad7dfc",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x0146176d40fbe8c38ce904c18b5c20f9bc984c8694bdcac896707b0c7bbfd13a",
        "fromAddress": "0x65cb3d6c18ddf6971a07bfae6e606eefafe2246d",
        "timeSent": 1534485733545,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485743949,
        "blockNumber": "699379",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf7238628f4f76f4bf15fea9621d83a414fc312c3",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x185381e0546607164ba53daa0080ec632be4362fbfc218e34cfeef139f1221e7",
        "fromAddress": "0xafafd671d866271578ce6490a54b60f1a30d3736",
        "timeSent": 1534485713502,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485722077,
        "blockNumber": "699375",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x0edf346fb0021d3534a1522994ce16adc63f8c27",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x12d2d340428fe68da8e9c92ba87c71c765bc9048fa93b8b13be6e87f968b9130",
        "fromAddress": "0x6db1dd4b5bee10d98300addf827145992a0b0bc6",
        "timeSent": 1534485695572,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485701597,
        "blockNumber": "699371",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf816368997e1dbfedf8de4da4ae834b566619fac",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xb10fb02b1fdaa99a69f178bf2a53559e4c1f4cee11f80e5d38ed27c0feebf3be",
        "fromAddress": "0x3e1d3eb628da78ce87dac0c0fdb518b6630d5a1b",
        "timeSent": 1534485668659,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485677395,
        "blockNumber": "699366",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x1d22cae5b6376cf2ec82ade5b8c2090df745948e",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xbd42f9ce7a302c5e227e8186194b48a9cafed49ee819dcbec59848525996368a",
        "fromAddress": "0xb1506cebb611394e84b731d6d857d6885108cbfb",
        "timeSent": 1534485648476,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485656795,
        "blockNumber": "699362",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x3468040e6060208fb3c16a12fd10b53e9fc5da9c",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xb66a693d2258e2270a602404cf1680e93757abacce16ce04e5ab17c35ef21c4f",
        "fromAddress": "0x0541be5fb74771dcc95ca6f99a651d635d618ddb",
        "timeSent": 1534485630149,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485637442,
        "blockNumber": "699358",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x85c2852c1cf8d2f8a4e73dee16116b48e378d6ba",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x79a6a4db781c9d7d4a75f66e4501b854c589679f797baa73695cdb1fda9557fd",
        "fromAddress": "0xcd1955bcf1cebc22e51e2d96d54fd1a4b1909985",
        "timeSent": 1534485599691,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485606434,
        "blockNumber": "699352",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf57e8580b4cf17adb7b557bb6e11e76a951eeeb1",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x192661f41251bfc7cef9dbdccc84b367f2ee77553c10427262eaaeda01baf8cc",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534485568393,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485576474,
        "blockNumber": "699346",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    }
]
console.log(
    _.groupBy(transactions,'timeSent'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

.

Comment: What do you mean by Date? By a Day?

Comment: What's the different if you group by timestamp or it's textual representation?

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy or https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy, you can pass a function that will determine the grouping criteria.

Comment: EOS > ETH & NEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you already use **lodash** you just need to use **function** in second parameter and return the value you want to be group.

`_.groupBy(transactions,({timeSent}) => new Date(timeSent).toDateString())`

```js
const transactions = [
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x5677f30d52ccea78e03a80597f978561abf763ec32bc2b2b9b7e3013527c0066",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534488092742,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534488101395,
        "blockNumber": "699851",
        "gasUsed": "28056",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "28056",
        "action": "addSignatory",
        "extraData": "documentId=69b1d781-7b56-4e97-9bc7-c6051df232ca",
        "property": "178"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x043d6f936d89dbe235dfa63c6cc511ddf82c3dc0d7c8a522adee3404ee72120b",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534488050259,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534488057529,
        "blockNumber": "699842",
        "gasUsed": "31512",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "31512",
        "action": "addDocument",
        "extraData": "documentId=69b1d781-7b56-4e97-9bc7-c6051df232ca",
        "property": "178"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xc4a8aef93084733a2155a71ee934dd31466a1de268c77ca3b48e3edf5aaa70ac",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534487694591,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "4300000",
        "timeMined": 1534487695066,
        "blockNumber": "699768",
        "gasUsed": "697650",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "697650",
        "action": "addSpatialUnit",
        "extraData": "propertyId=1"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x65a289854f5afc2a765e7217f1b5e1614a4318baa7ad9c298e2aa9f83cb4bce6",
        "fromAddress": "0x08a863e866cd8fe15d3c1e45c5d66e85440d724f",
        "timeSent": 1534485760789,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485766989,
        "blockNumber": "699384",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xfffd1812abccfd7e43ad326411060a3138ad7dfc",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x0146176d40fbe8c38ce904c18b5c20f9bc984c8694bdcac896707b0c7bbfd13a",
        "fromAddress": "0x65cb3d6c18ddf6971a07bfae6e606eefafe2246d",
        "timeSent": 1534485733545,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485743949,
        "blockNumber": "699379",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf7238628f4f76f4bf15fea9621d83a414fc312c3",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x185381e0546607164ba53daa0080ec632be4362fbfc218e34cfeef139f1221e7",
        "fromAddress": "0xafafd671d866271578ce6490a54b60f1a30d3736",
        "timeSent": 1534485713502,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485722077,
        "blockNumber": "699375",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x0edf346fb0021d3534a1522994ce16adc63f8c27",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x12d2d340428fe68da8e9c92ba87c71c765bc9048fa93b8b13be6e87f968b9130",
        "fromAddress": "0x6db1dd4b5bee10d98300addf827145992a0b0bc6",
        "timeSent": 1534485695572,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485701597,
        "blockNumber": "699371",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf816368997e1dbfedf8de4da4ae834b566619fac",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xb10fb02b1fdaa99a69f178bf2a53559e4c1f4cee11f80e5d38ed27c0feebf3be",
        "fromAddress": "0x3e1d3eb628da78ce87dac0c0fdb518b6630d5a1b",
        "timeSent": 1534485668659,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485677395,
        "blockNumber": "699366",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x1d22cae5b6376cf2ec82ade5b8c2090df745948e",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xbd42f9ce7a302c5e227e8186194b48a9cafed49ee819dcbec59848525996368a",
        "fromAddress": "0xb1506cebb611394e84b731d6d857d6885108cbfb",
        "timeSent": 1534485648476,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485656795,
        "blockNumber": "699362",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x3468040e6060208fb3c16a12fd10b53e9fc5da9c",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xb66a693d2258e2270a602404cf1680e93757abacce16ce04e5ab17c35ef21c4f",
        "fromAddress": "0x0541be5fb74771dcc95ca6f99a651d635d618ddb",
        "timeSent": 1534485630149,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485637442,
        "blockNumber": "699358",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x85c2852c1cf8d2f8a4e73dee16116b48e378d6ba",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x79a6a4db781c9d7d4a75f66e4501b854c589679f797baa73695cdb1fda9557fd",
        "fromAddress": "0xcd1955bcf1cebc22e51e2d96d54fd1a4b1909985",
        "timeSent": 1534485599691,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485606434,
        "blockNumber": "699352",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf57e8580b4cf17adb7b557bb6e11e76a951eeeb1",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x192661f41251bfc7cef9dbdccc84b367f2ee77553c10427262eaaeda01baf8cc",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534485568393,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485576474,
        "blockNumber": "699346",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    }
]
console.log(_.groupBy(transactions,({timeSent}) => new Date(timeSent).toDateString()))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to group them by day, you can do following:

```
_.groupBy(transactions, function(trans) {
     var dt = new Date(trans.timeSent);
     return dt.getFullYear() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. Just pass a function that will generate a key by date as the grouping criteria and pass it to the `groupBy` function.

```js
const transactions = [
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x5677f30d52ccea78e03a80597f978561abf763ec32bc2b2b9b7e3013527c0066",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534488092742,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534488101395,
        "blockNumber": "699851",
        "gasUsed": "28056",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "28056",
        "action": "addSignatory",
        "extraData": "documentId=69b1d781-7b56-4e97-9bc7-c6051df232ca",
        "property": "178"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x043d6f936d89dbe235dfa63c6cc511ddf82c3dc0d7c8a522adee3404ee72120b",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534488050259,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534488057529,
        "blockNumber": "699842",
        "gasUsed": "31512",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "31512",
        "action": "addDocument",
        "extraData": "documentId=69b1d781-7b56-4e97-9bc7-c6051df232ca",
        "property": "178"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xc4a8aef93084733a2155a71ee934dd31466a1de268c77ca3b48e3edf5aaa70ac",
        "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534487694591,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "4300000",
        "timeMined": 1534487695066,
        "blockNumber": "699768",
        "gasUsed": "697650",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "697650",
        "action": "addSpatialUnit",
        "extraData": "propertyId=1"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x65a289854f5afc2a765e7217f1b5e1614a4318baa7ad9c298e2aa9f83cb4bce6",
        "fromAddress": "0x08a863e866cd8fe15d3c1e45c5d66e85440d724f",
        "timeSent": 1534485760789,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485766989,
        "blockNumber": "699384",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xfffd1812abccfd7e43ad326411060a3138ad7dfc",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x0146176d40fbe8c38ce904c18b5c20f9bc984c8694bdcac896707b0c7bbfd13a",
        "fromAddress": "0x65cb3d6c18ddf6971a07bfae6e606eefafe2246d",
        "timeSent": 1534485733545,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485743949,
        "blockNumber": "699379",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf7238628f4f76f4bf15fea9621d83a414fc312c3",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x185381e0546607164ba53daa0080ec632be4362fbfc218e34cfeef139f1221e7",
        "fromAddress": "0xafafd671d866271578ce6490a54b60f1a30d3736",
        "timeSent": 1534485713502,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485722077,
        "blockNumber": "699375",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x0edf346fb0021d3534a1522994ce16adc63f8c27",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x12d2d340428fe68da8e9c92ba87c71c765bc9048fa93b8b13be6e87f968b9130",
        "fromAddress": "0x6db1dd4b5bee10d98300addf827145992a0b0bc6",
        "timeSent": 1534485695572,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485701597,
        "blockNumber": "699371",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf816368997e1dbfedf8de4da4ae834b566619fac",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xb10fb02b1fdaa99a69f178bf2a53559e4c1f4cee11f80e5d38ed27c0feebf3be",
        "fromAddress": "0x3e1d3eb628da78ce87dac0c0fdb518b6630d5a1b",
        "timeSent": 1534485668659,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485677395,
        "blockNumber": "699366",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x1d22cae5b6376cf2ec82ade5b8c2090df745948e",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xbd42f9ce7a302c5e227e8186194b48a9cafed49ee819dcbec59848525996368a",
        "fromAddress": "0xb1506cebb611394e84b731d6d857d6885108cbfb",
        "timeSent": 1534485648476,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485656795,
        "blockNumber": "699362",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x3468040e6060208fb3c16a12fd10b53e9fc5da9c",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xb66a693d2258e2270a602404cf1680e93757abacce16ce04e5ab17c35ef21c4f",
        "fromAddress": "0x0541be5fb74771dcc95ca6f99a651d635d618ddb",
        "timeSent": 1534485630149,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485637442,
        "blockNumber": "699358",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x85c2852c1cf8d2f8a4e73dee16116b48e378d6ba",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x79a6a4db781c9d7d4a75f66e4501b854c589679f797baa73695cdb1fda9557fd",
        "fromAddress": "0xcd1955bcf1cebc22e51e2d96d54fd1a4b1909985",
        "timeSent": 1534485599691,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485606434,
        "blockNumber": "699352",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0xf57e8580b4cf17adb7b557bb6e11e76a951eeeb1",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x192661f41251bfc7cef9dbdccc84b367f2ee77553c10427262eaaeda01baf8cc",
        "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
        "timeSent": 1534485568393,
        "gasPrice": "0",
        "gasLimit": "2000000",
        "timeMined": 1534485576474,
        "blockNumber": "699346",
        "gasUsed": "54344",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
        "contractAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
        "action": "createIdentity"
    }
]
console.log(_.groupBy(transactions, t => {
  const d = new Date(t.timeSent)
  return d.getDate()+'-'+d.getMonth()+'-'+d.getFullYear()
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new final array for your expected output by looping through to the grouped result. Something like this:

```js
const transactions = [{
    "transactionHash": "0x5677f30d52ccea78e03a80597f978561abf763ec32bc2b2b9b7e3013527c0066",
    "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
    "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
    "timeSent": 1534488092742,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534488101395,
    "blockNumber": "699851",
    "gasUsed": "28056",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "28056",
    "action": "addSignatory",
    "extraData": "documentId=69b1d781-7b56-4e97-9bc7-c6051df232ca",
    "property": "178"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0x043d6f936d89dbe235dfa63c6cc511ddf82c3dc0d7c8a522adee3404ee72120b",
    "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
    "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
    "timeSent": 1534488050259,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534488057529,
    "blockNumber": "699842",
    "gasUsed": "31512",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "31512",
    "action": "addDocument",
    "extraData": "documentId=69b1d781-7b56-4e97-9bc7-c6051df232ca",
    "property": "178"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0xc4a8aef93084733a2155a71ee934dd31466a1de268c77ca3b48e3edf5aaa70ac",
    "toAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
    "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
    "timeSent": 1534487694591,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "4300000",
    "timeMined": 1534487695066,
    "blockNumber": "699768",
    "gasUsed": "697650",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "697650",
    "action": "addSpatialUnit",
    "extraData": "propertyId=1"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0x65a289854f5afc2a765e7217f1b5e1614a4318baa7ad9c298e2aa9f83cb4bce6",
    "fromAddress": "0x08a863e866cd8fe15d3c1e45c5d66e85440d724f",
    "timeSent": 1534485760789,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485766989,
    "blockNumber": "699384",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0xfffd1812abccfd7e43ad326411060a3138ad7dfc",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0x0146176d40fbe8c38ce904c18b5c20f9bc984c8694bdcac896707b0c7bbfd13a",
    "fromAddress": "0x65cb3d6c18ddf6971a07bfae6e606eefafe2246d",
    "timeSent": 1534485733545,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485743949,
    "blockNumber": "699379",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0xf7238628f4f76f4bf15fea9621d83a414fc312c3",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0x185381e0546607164ba53daa0080ec632be4362fbfc218e34cfeef139f1221e7",
    "fromAddress": "0xafafd671d866271578ce6490a54b60f1a30d3736",
    "timeSent": 1534485713502,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485722077,
    "blockNumber": "699375",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0x0edf346fb0021d3534a1522994ce16adc63f8c27",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0x12d2d340428fe68da8e9c92ba87c71c765bc9048fa93b8b13be6e87f968b9130",
    "fromAddress": "0x6db1dd4b5bee10d98300addf827145992a0b0bc6",
    "timeSent": 1534485695572,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485701597,
    "blockNumber": "699371",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0xf816368997e1dbfedf8de4da4ae834b566619fac",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0xb10fb02b1fdaa99a69f178bf2a53559e4c1f4cee11f80e5d38ed27c0feebf3be",
    "fromAddress": "0x3e1d3eb628da78ce87dac0c0fdb518b6630d5a1b",
    "timeSent": 1534485668659,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485677395,
    "blockNumber": "699366",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0x1d22cae5b6376cf2ec82ade5b8c2090df745948e",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0xbd42f9ce7a302c5e227e8186194b48a9cafed49ee819dcbec59848525996368a",
    "fromAddress": "0xb1506cebb611394e84b731d6d857d6885108cbfb",
    "timeSent": 1534485648476,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485656795,
    "blockNumber": "699362",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0x3468040e6060208fb3c16a12fd10b53e9fc5da9c",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0xb66a693d2258e2270a602404cf1680e93757abacce16ce04e5ab17c35ef21c4f",
    "fromAddress": "0x0541be5fb74771dcc95ca6f99a651d635d618ddb",
    "timeSent": 1534485630149,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485637442,
    "blockNumber": "699358",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0x85c2852c1cf8d2f8a4e73dee16116b48e378d6ba",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0x79a6a4db781c9d7d4a75f66e4501b854c589679f797baa73695cdb1fda9557fd",
    "fromAddress": "0xcd1955bcf1cebc22e51e2d96d54fd1a4b1909985",
    "timeSent": 1534485599691,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485606434,
    "blockNumber": "699352",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0xf57e8580b4cf17adb7b557bb6e11e76a951eeeb1",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  },
  {
    "transactionHash": "0x192661f41251bfc7cef9dbdccc84b367f2ee77553c10427262eaaeda01baf8cc",
    "fromAddress": "0x1b5a27f4db96580b6e1e35514d28572fb5b3843c",
    "timeSent": 1534485568393,
    "gasPrice": "0",
    "gasLimit": "2000000",
    "timeMined": 1534485576474,
    "blockNumber": "699346",
    "gasUsed": "54344",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "54344",
    "contractAddress": "0x933b3d3129d53a0173be68ae478902f41f78d9a9",
    "action": "createIdentity"
  }
];

var group = _.groupBy(transactions, 'timeSent');
var res = [];
Object.keys(group).forEach(key => res.push({[new Date(+key).toISOString()]: group[key]}));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Without underscore/lodash* you can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). If you want to use a real `Date` as group key in a collection, using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) comes to mind

```js
const transactions = getTransactions();

// Map (keys are real Dates)
let transactionsMap = new Map();
transactions.forEach( value => transactionsMap.set(new Date(value.timeSent), value) );
const firstEntry = transactionsMap.entries().next().value;
console.log("transactionsMap first entry:", firstEntry);
console.log("First entry of transactionsMap: key is Date?", firstEntry[0] instanceof Date);

// reducer (keys are strings)
console.log(transactions.reduce( (reduced, value) => 
     ({...reduced, [new Date(value.timeSent).toUTCString()]: value}), {}));

function getTransactions() {
return [
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x5677f30d52ccea78e03a80597f978561abf763ec32bc2b2b9b7e3013527c0066",
        "timeSent": 1534488092742,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x043d6f936d89dbe235dfa63c6cc511ddf82c3dc0d7c8a522adee3404ee72120b",
        "timeSent": 1534488050259,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xc4a8aef93084733a2155a71ee934dd31466a1de268c77ca3b48e3edf5aaa70ac",
        "timeSent": 1534487694591,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x65a289854f5afc2a765e7217f1b5e1614a4318baa7ad9c298e2aa9f83cb4bce6",
        "timeSent": 1534485760789,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x0146176d40fbe8c38ce904c18b5c20f9bc984c8694bdcac896707b0c7bbfd13a",
        "timeSent": 1534485733545,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x185381e0546607164ba53daa0080ec632be4362fbfc218e34cfeef139f1221e7",
        "timeSent": 1534485713502,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x12d2d340428fe68da8e9c92ba87c71c765bc9048fa93b8b13be6e87f968b9130",
        "timeSent": 1534485695572,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xb10fb02b1fdaa99a69f178bf2a53559e4c1f4cee11f80e5d38ed27c0feebf3be",
        "timeSent": 1534485668659,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xbd42f9ce7a302c5e227e8186194b48a9cafed49ee819dcbec59848525996368a",
        "timeSent": 1534485648476,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0xb66a693d2258e2270a602404cf1680e93757abacce16ce04e5ab17c35ef21c4f",
        "timeSent": 1534485630149,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x79a6a4db781c9d7d4a75f66e4501b854c589679f797baa73695cdb1fda9557fd",
        "timeSent": 1534485599691,
    },
    {
        "transactionHash": "0x192661f41251bfc7cef9dbdccc84b367f2ee77553c10427262eaaeda01baf8cc",
        "timeSent": 1534485568393,
    }
  ];
}
```